# Musicplayer stops when navigating on the site

Tags: html, wordpress, audio

How can I make the musicplayer on this page to play continuously, even if you are going from the frontpage to a sub-page? Like it is now, it stops when you enter the next page or if you refresh.

I use Wordpress with a custom made WP template btw.

http://cpanel12.proisp.no/~annaryuh/

Comment: 1) That player does not preserve the track or position when changing pages for me. 2) It is not using Java.

Answer (score 1):

This Wordpress plugin may helps you - [**Audiobar**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/audiobar/).

> Audiobar is a stylish audio player bar that continues playing when visitors browse

Some other plugins for better music play in Wordpress:

1. [Blubrry PowerPress Podcasting plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/powerpress/)
2. [Audio Playlist Manager with Autoresume](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tierra-audio-with-autoresume/)

Also you can use HTML5 `<audio>` tag to insert a sound file on your website. Check this article: [Mastering the HTML5 audio tag](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/mastering-the-html5-audio-property)

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thank you! I was considering to use plugins like Audiobar but my client wanted it to be designed like you saw on the page.

What about make the website into AJAX?  Would that be a good solution?

Comment: My suggestion is to stick with WordPress and achieve your goal.